# no static method "Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Landroid/content/Context;)I"

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I'm updating a Xamarin Forms Maps App. I'm currently experiencing this error:

```
no static method "Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Landroid/content/Context;)I"
```

It happens on this line within the MainActivity class:

```
Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
```

I currently have proguard configured to keep the GooglePlayServicesUtil class:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
```

Here are my Android Nuget packages:

[image]

Here is my Android project config:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: as you can see in google document https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil the method is deprecated use GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context) instead.

Comment: This method is handled internally this is a Xamarin Forms App.

Comment: how about update the packages to the latest version

Comment: I tried updating Xamarin Forms & Xamarin Forms Maps to the latest version and that didn't work. I'm not sure what other packages I should update as there is limited documentation out there about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually edit the project file to disable the multi-dex functionality. Disabling multi-dex and removing the code shrinker from the project properties did not do the trick.

Comment: You could mark your answer